# RegExp match with lastIndex results in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, regex, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop

The following code always results in an infinite loop, and I have no idea why.

```js
var regex1 = /Hi([^]*?)Hi/g
var str = `
Hi my name is Hi
`;

function doStuff(str) {
  var lastMatchIndex = 0
    while ((m = regex1.exec(str)) !== null) {
        console.log("it's not null")
        //firstblock is the content between the 2 hi's
        var firstblock = m[1] || ""
        if (firstblock !== "") {
            console.log(doStuff(firstblock))
        }
    }
    return str
}
doStuff(str)
```

I would assume that the while loop would occur once, and `firstblock` would be equal to " my name is ". When I called `console.log(doStuff(firstblock))` there would be no matches, so the while loop would not execute, and it would print " my  name is " to the screen. What's going wrong?

I'll attach an example, BUT IT MAY CRASH YOUR BROWSER TAB. BE WARNED. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `return;` inside the `if` condition to prevent infinite loop from the outer recursion function. The `console.log(doStuff(firstblock))` will call the `doStuff` function second time and then this second call will simply return `str`. The control is passed to the calling recursive function and now this function needs to return the control to `doStuff(str)` otherwise the `while` loop will execute infinitely.

```js
var regex1 = /Hi([^]*?)Hi/g
var str = `Hi my name is Hi`;

function doStuff(str) {
  var lastMatchIndex = 0
  while ((m = regex1.exec(str)) !== null) {
    console.log("it's not null")
    //firstblock is the content between the 2 hi's
    var firstblock = m[1] || ""
    if (firstblock !== "") {
        console.log(doStuff(firstblock));
        return;
    }
  }
  return str
}
doStuff(str)
```

Comment: This works... but there's one problem. If you had a str like 'Hi my name is Hi Hi my name is Ben Hi' it only logs the first match.